Is there a way to slow down digitalWrite/analogWrite/ledcWrite functions?
I'm building an alarm using ESP32, and it seems like there are voltage "leaks" between random pins. I have 3 LEDs (they use ledcWrite), a buzzer (analogWrite) and a 4-digit 7-segment indicator (digitalWrite). 
Examples (for the newer version of the code):

When either the red or yellow LED is on and not on max brightness, the buzzer starts making sounds (although quiet).
The F-cathode of the indicator doesn't work (in an older version of the code, it was the red LED that didn't work).
Before I replaced analogWrite with ledcWrite for LEDs, the red LED would turn on and off about 1-2 seconds later than the yellow and white ones.
Also, each LED only displays 3 levels of brightness: off, about 50% and 100%.
So, as it seems, sometimes writing functions accidentally influences the wrong pin. The LEDs and the buzzer are on two different breadboards. 

So is there a way to give writing functions more time to process the operation? 
Here's a short version of the code that replicates some problems:
uint8_t  BUZZER_pin = 4;
uint8_t  LED_red_pin = 18,
         LED_yellow_pin = 5,
         LED_white_pin = 17;

uint32_t BUZZER_timer = 0,
         BUZZER_delay = 500,
         BUZZER_state = 0;
bool     BUZZER_hard_off = 1;
uint32_t LED_timer = 0, 
         LED_delay = 250;
uint8_t  LED_state = 0;
bool     LED_direction = 0,
         LED_hard_on = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUZZER_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_red_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_yellow_pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_white_pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {  
  blink_slowly();
  buzz_off();
}

void buzz_off() {
  analogWrite(BUZZER_pin, 0); 
  BUZZER_state = 0;
}

void blink_slowly() {
  if(millis() - LED_timer >= LED_delay) {
    set_light_state(LED_state);
    if(!LED_direction)
      LED_state++;
    else
      LED_state--;
    if(LED_state == 0 || LED_state == 20)
      LED_direction = !LED_direction;
    LED_timer = millis();
  }
}

void set_light_state(uint8_t state) {
  switch (state) {
    default: set_light(0, 0, 0); break;
    case 1: set_light(26, 0, 0); break;
    case 2: set_light(51, 0, 0); break;
    case 3: set_light(77, 0, 0); break;
    case 4: set_light(102, 0, 0); break;
    case 5: set_light(128, 0, 0); break;
    case 6: set_light(153, 26, 0); break;
    case 7: set_light(128, 51, 0); break;
    case 8: set_light(102, 77, 0); break;
    case 9: set_light(77, 102, 0); break;
    case 10: set_light(51, 128, 0); break;
    case 11: set_light(26, 153, 0); break;
    case 12: set_light(0, 128, 26); break;
    case 13: set_light(0, 102, 51); break;
    case 14: set_light(0, 77, 77); break;
    case 15: set_light(0, 51, 102); break;
    case 16: set_light(0, 26, 128); break;
    case 17: set_light(0, 0, 153); break;
    case 18: set_light(0, 0, 179); break;
    case 19: set_light(0, 0, 204); break;
    case 20: set_light(0, 0, 255); break;
  }
}

void set_light(uint8_t red, uint8_t yellow, uint8_t white) {
  analogWrite(LED_yellow_pin, yellow);
  analogWrite(LED_red_pin, red);
  analogWrite(LED_white_pin, white);
}

The weird behaviors in this are:

The buzzer should be constantly off; however, it buzzes while the LEDs blink.
The red LED does not work at all. When lines that analogWrite into red and yellow LEDs are switched, the yellow LED stops working instead.

I attempted to use ledcWrite to see whether it would influence the short code, and it didn't.
However, slowing down the program (e.g., adding a Serial.print at 2400 bod) results in the red LED working correctly (with the buzzer still making sounds).

LED Control (LEDC) take much more setup than your code is showing.

@hcheung Thank you for the answer. I know, and I use it in the main program. Using led control doesn't influence the snippet in the question, so I didn't include any code for it.
